# GCP Kubernetes not using service account for pulling docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the latest version of google-kubernetes (1.22.8-gke.202) in a Kubernetes managed cluster. I also have a custom service account that has access to the "Artifact Registry Reader" scope that should grant it permission to pull private images from the repository - calling this *custom-service-account*.

I've validated that the nodes themselves have the *custom-service-account* service account linked to them within Compute Engine. Kubernetes is setup with a service account that is linked to the IAM service account with the same name through [workload identity](https://www.cobalt.io/blog/google-cloud-workload-identity-with-kubernetes-and-terraform). However, when I try to spawn a pod that pulls from my private repo it fails indefinitely.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                   From                Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----                -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling   21m (x3 over 24m)     default-scheduler   0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) were unschedulable.
  Warning  FailedScheduling   19m                   default-scheduler   no nodes available to schedule pods
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  18m (x25 over 24m)    cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up: 1 node(s) had taint {reserved-pool: true}, that the pod didn't tolerate
  Normal   Scheduled          18m                   default-scheduler   Successfully assigned default/test-service-a-deployment-5757fc5797-b54gx to gke-personal-XXXX--personal-XXXX--ac9a05b6-16sb
  Normal   Pulling            17m (x4 over 18m)     kubelet             Pulling image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/personal-XXXX/my-test-repo/my-test-repo-business-logic:latest"
  Warning  Failed             17m (x4 over 18m)     kubelet             Failed to pull image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/personal-XXXX/my-test-repo/my-test-repo-business-logic:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/personal-XXXX/my-test-repo/my-test-repo-business-logic:latest": failed to resolve reference "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/personal-XXXX/my-test-repo/my-test-repo-business-logic:latest": failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 403 Forbidden
  Warning  Failed             17m (x4 over 18m)     kubelet             Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed             16m (x6 over 18m)     kubelet             Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff            3m27s (x65 over 18m)  kubelet             Back-off pulling image "us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/personal-XXXX/my-test-repo/my-test-repo-business-logic:latest"
```

I've also ssh'ed into the nodes themselves and at least by default with a regular `docker pull` or `crictl pull` see this same error.

So, the specific questions I have:

- How is GCP injecting the service account credentials into Kubernetes/Docker worker that tries to launch the images? Is it expected that the regular docker command doesn't seem to have these credentials?
- Do I need to manually bootstrap some additional authentication for Kubernetes aside from just inheriting the service account on the pods?

EDIT: Result of [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#troubleshooting)

```
> gcloud container clusters describe personal-XXXX-gke --zone us-central1-a --format="value(workloadIdentityConfig.workloadPool)"
personal-XXXX.svc.id.goog

> gcloud container node-pools describe personal-XXXX-gke-node-pool --cluster personal-XXXX-gke --format="value(config.workloadMetadataConfig.mode)" --zone us-central1-a
GKE_METADATA

> kubectl describe serviceaccount --namespace default be-service-account
Name:                be-service-account
Namespace:           default
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: custom-service-account@personal-XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   be-service-account-token-jmss9
Tokens:              be-service-account-token-jmss9
Events:              <none>

> gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy custom-service-account@personal-XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:personal-XXXX.svc.id.goog[default/be-service-account]
  role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser
etag: BwXjqJ9DC6A=
version: 1
```

Comment: Did you go through this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#troubleshooting ?

Comment: @danyL Have confirmed steps 1-5 (edited my post with the specifics) but unsure how to check 6 for whether the cluster network policy is correct. I haven't done anything explicitly to configure one, not sure if GCP sets one up automatically or if my other firewall rules on the VPC level happen to be blocking them. I can access the open web however so I doubt that’s an issue

Comment: Because of this error [unexpected status: 403 Forbidden], i do not think its a network issue, so we can neglect 6 for now. Did you check scopes? https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#gke

Comment: @danyL Scopes of the service account are correct. Do you mean scopes of the node itself?

Comment: Yes on cluster/node-pools.

Comment: @danyL I've explicitly added the "cloud-platform" scope to the node pool, and that seems to work. But the docs mention that "By default, creating a cluster or node pool with a custom service account grants the cloud-platform access scope." Any idea why this doesn't seem to be the case and why this particular scope is required?

Comment: I am not sure, did you use terraform? This is another question you can post on another stack. I will put an answer if the above helped. You can report here if you suspect its a bug: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When checking for access to artifact registry, please check permission and scopes as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#gke).

Comment: This helped, thanks. I had one of two node pools missing the scope `cloud-platform` which was causing intermittent failures. You can see what scopes your node pools have with the `$ gcloud container clusters describe ...` command.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your cluster is created, various scopes are added. https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/access-scopes#create_with_sa

In my case, I created Autopilot cluster from the console (UI) and did everything you did w.r.t linking service accounts - turns out the default service account that gets applied does not get the scope cloud-platform.

I ended up re-creating the cluster with the right service account (non-default) for my autopilot nodes. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create#--scopes. Most likely to use the CLI for future creations.